# Given S ⊆ R2 a convex set, the function f : S → R will be convex if...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I got this question in my multivariable calculus class where the answer's supposed to be option (c):

3. Given S ⊆ R2 a convex set, the function f : S → R will be convex if

(a) the Hessian matrix Hf(x, y) is negative definite for all (x, y) in S.

(b) the sets {(x, y) ∈ S/f(x, y) ≤ k} are convex for all k in R.

(c) f is a lineal function.

What is the reasoning for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a function $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ will be convex if
$$
\forall a, b \in S, t \in [0,1] : f((1-t)a + tb) \leq (1-t)f(a) + tf(b) .
$$

To check that this works if $f$ is linear, just take an arbitrary linear function $f$ and use its properties to conclude that the above inequality holds (in fact one even has equality in this case).